# File permission for ElasticSearch synonyms path

Tags: php, linux, apache, elasticsearch, laravel-5

I'm kinda stuck here, probably due to my insufficient experience with users and groups.

I'm using ElasticSearch in Laravel 5.2 and set up a synonyms file, which by default resides in the */etc/ES/analysis* directory. I want to update it once in a while so I thought I'd move it inside Laravel's *storage* directory. After that I'd reopen the node so I don't have to reindex everytime I add a synonym.

My problem is now that I can't add that directory as *synonyms_path* to my node's settings, I receive an error:

**Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/var/www/laravelproject/storage/app/elasticquent_synonyms.txt" "read")**

Probably because the ES and Web service are run by different users or something like that!? I tried adjusting permissions to no avail. The whole *storage* in Laravel is set to be readable for anyone, anyways.

I can't access it the other way around, either, cant write to */etc/elasticsearch/analysis* from my web app. And having the synonyms file outside my actual project doesn't feel right, anyway.

Could anybody give me a hint on what I could do to circumvent this problem?

Comment: did you find any solution about ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: I found for my self, I will try to post a solution asap

Comment: Could you @beast caged please accept my answer if you think it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution. Thank you. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, it's Java security policy issue, to solve it you need to find where does the **vjm** is located:
Normally it should be under:  `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/java.policy`

Edit the file with sudo permission and then add this grant configuration, at the end of the policy file.

```
grant {
    permission java.io.FilePermission "/var/www/laravelproject/storage/app/elasticquent_synonyms.txt", "read,write";
};
```

Comment: Thanks (+1) - on the Mac, the file was at Macintosh HD⁩/⁨Library⁩/⁨Java⁩/⁨JavaVirtualMachines⁩/⁨jdk1.8.0_111.jdk⁩/⁨Contents⁩/⁨Home⁩/⁨jre/⁨lib⁩/⁨security⁩/java.policy. Couldn't edit it though since it said the file cannot be edited (there may be a workaround  - did not search for it - just decided to keep it in ES /config dir)